# O que é Fat JAR?

Tags: java, jar

Em meus estudos diários sobre Java na internet, encontrei algumas referências e comentários de programadores usando essa denominação "Fat JAR", no contexto de configuração e deploy de aplicações Java.

Como pra mim não fincou muito claro o que seria esse "JAR Gordo", recorro aos colegas para me ajudarem na definição do termo "Fat JAR", o que lhe difere de um JAR tradicional, e qual seria a vantagem de uso.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O fat jar, contem além do seu código, todas as dependências que ele precisa para rodar, ou seja ele pega o seu código mais as dependências do seu projeto e tudo isso é empacotado para um único arquivo jar, esta solução é bastante usada em servidores onde não se tem internet.

Acabei encontrando alguns outros tipos, como:

Skinny – Contém somente o código criado e nada mais.

Thin – Contem tudo do anterior mais as dependências diretas da aplicação, drivers do banco, bibliotecas e afins

Hollow – O inverso do Thin, contem somente o código necessário para rodar a aplicação mas não contem a aplicação em si.

Fat/Uber – Contem o código criado mais as dependências necessárias para rodar o programa por si só

[image: Tipos de pacotes jar]

Fonte: https://dzone.com/articles/the-skinny-on-fat-thin-hollow-and-uber

Answer (score 2):

O normal é suas classes serem compiladas para arquivos `jar` individuais, com o Fat Jar você tem tudo em uma arquivo só. É só isso. Há uma vantagem porque os arquivos não ficam soltos e não podem ser apagados indevidamente, fica mais fácil fazer o *deploy* e deixar tudo em ordem. Então é só uma forma de empacotar o código, mas são os mesmos *bytecodes* que sempre teve antes, ele não é um executável.

Comment: então não passa de um nome diferente para denominar o jar que normalmente geramos ao termino do desenvolvimento de nossas aplicações para realização do deploy em um servidor ou fornecimento ao cliente? Pelo visto sempre fiz isso, só não conhecia por esse nome.